# Can I enter Mexico with valid US visa but in my old passport?

Tags: visas, passports, mexico

I renewed my passport recently. My US visa is in my old passport and is still valid (expires on October 2017). I know I can re-enter the US with both my old and new passport.

Does Mexico accept this as a valid US visa and allow me in?

Comment: @pnuts why does that matter...? Renewed passport + old passport holding visa I thought is universally accepted as if the visa was in the new passport.

Comment: @chx it matters because it's possible that OP doesn't need to show the US visa in the first place

Comment: is it certain?
because I am planning the same thing

Comment: Why would you trust a 'yes it is certain' more than the answer already given? Either go with the answer given or ask a new question if your situation is different.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, But you should show both passports, The old with the US visa, and the new passport, You can process your FMM for internet, and present when you entry to Mexico, for air or land.

The foreigners with an US visa, can stay in Mexico from 30 days for visitors in transit, and up to 180 days for tourist and business visits.  It's important that you keep safe the FMM sealed, because you will be asked for this document at your departure from Mexico.